# Names of friends in array

Tags: facebook

I need to make an facebook app for school.
Is it possible to retrieve names of the person who signed in and put them in an array?
I'm making this app in actionscript 3.0

Comment: short answer, yes it is possible.  http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/ may be a good starting point.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using Facebook PHP-SDK

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId' => 'Your_app_id',
                'secret' => 'Your_app_Secret',
                'cookie' => true,
            ));


    // Getting friends list
    $friends = $facebook->api('/me/friends');


    foreach ($friends as $friends1) {
      foreach ($friends1 as $friend) {

         $id = $friend['id'];
         $name = $friend['name'];
      }
   }
```

Comment: I am not sure why this was voted down unless it is because it does not make use of actionscript.  This is a valid serverside solution to the question asked.  Given that it is specified that the app is being built in actionscript however a clientside solution involving the AS3 SDK would be in order.  That said, a similar logic can be employed using the other SDK.